# The best way to transfer large file (>100MB) over http

Tags: javascript, html, web

Or should I not do it using HTTP at all? I want to upload a file from an HTML web page (an HTML form). Can I simply go the way I do for a 5MB file? What help can I take from HTML5 and JavaScript

Comment: I know the Server side stuff like increasing the timeout, etc. That is not helping

Answer (score 0):

There is a new feature in HTML5 where you can upload files via DnD(Drag and Drop) in an area...

I think this is a good stuff you can try that, this is by using HTML5, Jquery, Javascript and Some PHP Code..

[Try This](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are many ways to do it.

- **Flash** ( sorry... but it's still a solid way of doing it, [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [swfupload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) )
- **HTML5** new APIs like SaurabhLP have been advicing ( but you kill your browser support )
- **JAVA Applet** ( not too bad, but a little heavy, a nice one at [Java Applet File Uploader](http://jumploader.com/) )
- Or maybe **websockets** streams could even do it very nicely ( Browser support is also an issue, you can find a nice and interesting thread about it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/okrb/o25DlPJ2afg), with some projects ).

I think you should look how other companies are doing it, like Web ***Picasa*** ( not really good example as most of files are less than 5mo ) but ***YouSendIt*** is a solid actor ( I think they're using Flash, but should check ) as well as ***Youtube/Vimeo/DailyMotion/Video actors***.
I suppose you'll learn a lot from them.

A small note added that I think that the biggest issue will be connection breaking the transfer. Then you'll need "ideally" either a solid software that is able to wait up for the connection to resume or a piece of software that will - server-side - allow resuming of the upload.

Comment: "not too bad" - i'd rather say **completely horrible**. Loading the Java VM takes much longer than e.g. a flash application, it usually looks much different and I think much more people have flash enabled than Java.

Comment: Yes. It's heavy and not sexy at all - especially from a user experience point of view. But still a very solid alternative. Especially feature-wise ( I have upload resuming in mind ).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [plupload](http://www.plupload.com) for this. It's a solid, open-source solution with support for multiple backends like html5, flash, silverlight and gears and even html4 fallback. Does chunked uploading and client-side image scaling.